# Resources on the energy consumption of IBM quantum computers?

Tags: quantum-gate, resource-request, ibm-quantum-devices

I am seeking information regarding the energy consumption of IBM Quantum Computers, specifically inquiring about the energy requirements associated with individual gate operations.
Could you also provide any available resources or documentation detailing the energy consumption of IBM Quantum Computers and the energy requirements for executing one gate operation?

Comment: Take a look at [this work](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/working_papers/WRA2400/WRA2427-1/RAND_WRA2427-1.pdf), and [this](https://spectrum.ieee.org/how-much-power-will-quantum-computing-need), or [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2188804_Minimum_energy_needed_to_perform_a_quantum_logical_gate),